# How do I get per-port traffic statistics when using DSA?

Tags: linux, networking, openwrt

I have an embedded device running OpenWRT. I have recently started testing with the newer (23.05-rc3) builds that use the DSA (distributed switch architecture) feature in Linux. One of the issues I am running in to is that the values reported in `/proc/net/dev` are no longer accurate. Previously I would poll this file and monitor changes in the `bytes` field for each interface to keep running statistics on how much traffic traversed each port. After the update from 22.03 (which did not use DSA), these values are now *much* lower than expected. I can plug in to one of the ports, download a 4GB file, and the `bytes` value will only increse by a few MB.

This sort-of makes sense. The goal of DSA is to allow the kernel to offload work to the switch hardware whenever possible. Presumably most packets aren't getting counted in `/proc/net/dev` because they are no longer seen by the kernel. Is there any way to get access to this information though? For example, does DSA expose some way to query statistics on the switch itself?

If not, is there some way to exclude a specific port from DSA's hardware acceleration so I can monitor traffic on it again?